# Is it ethical to use a recommendation letter from a deceased professor?

Tags: ethics, recommendation-letter, death

She was a really nice professor and she wrote me a good recommendation letter that resulted in a lot of good results with applications. Recently, this professor died from brain cancer, which was a fast and shocking death for me.

Tomorrow is the deadline for a grant. What should I do? Is it professional to use letters from the deceased?

Comment: I should say, if you have access to the letter (i.e. European-style reference where the candidate submits the - open - letter), and you can be confident that there were no shift in situation which would have given her reason to change the letter, I do not think it is unethical per se. You might need to mention that she is deceased now - but I have no strong opinion on that. People do pass away, unfortunately also referees, so it should be understandable. It may be a problem if the letter is very old.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I think if you do that you **must** disclose that you are using a recommendation letter without the consent of the giver, and explain why.

Comment: @Bitwise: If the letter was completely finished and ready to be sent the way the OP received it, and if the letter was supposed to be read and submitted by the candidate, as outlined by Captain Emacs above, then the professor *did* consent before passing away, by the very action of handing over the letter to the OP. Otherwise, I agree.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs it is open still letter, beginning with To whom it may concern.

Comment: @Bitwise why would someone write the letter without consent? Now maybe is difficult to check that.

Comment: @Bitwise If the referee was alive, I do not think that they would expect to check how often that letter was used. A different thing would be if they have had a recent, unpleasant experience with their protege and would have actively retracted it. Barring that, I do not think that the situation is much different to reusing the letter without extra notice (which is not expected by the giver, either, when the letter is openly readable, as sometimes in Europe). It may be good practice, though, to disclose the passing away of the referee. As I said, I have no strong opinion on that.

Comment: "I attach letters of recommendation from Dr W and the late Professor X." Perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Bitwise Why? A letter of recommendation is intended to be used. Otherwise why write it?

Comment: @EJP it depends if the letter is general-purpose or not. In many fields recommendations are often given for a specific grant/fellowship/prize - in this case it would be not be appropriate to use the letter for a different purpose without mentioning consent. However, even if the letter is general, I would argue that there is always a small chance that the giver would change her mind and ask not to use it (an extreme example would be if the receiver committed scientific fraud). Now she does not have the chance to change her mind, hence I think the clarification is needed anyway.

Comment: @SSimon What is the ethical dilema you see here?

Comment: If the individual who wrote the letter of rec. isn't alive, how can a recipient of the letter validate it's authenticity?

Comment: @thepip3r good point

Answer (score 89, accepted):

If I cared enough about a person to write a letter of recommendation, I would be pleased to think that one day after I am gone that the person could use my letter for their benefit.

You will possibly benefit from this recommendation and possibly someone else will suffer if you are selected based upon the recommendation; however, competition is not generally considered unethical.

There are no legal questions raised that I can imagine.

It seems unconventional, but not extreme.

My feelings are that it would be ethical to use the letter.

Comment: Re: your second paragraph... isn't that the point of recommendation letters? That you get propelled to the top of the line by having someone willing to put their name behind you?

Answer (score 84):

> I attach letters of recommendation from Dr W and the late Professor X.

Perfectly reasonable.

The point is, it's courteous to refer to the deceased as *the late* Professor X to prevent confusion or embarrassment and to avoid unnecessary pain to the bereaved.

If you don't do this, and the widower receives a letter addressed to his wife that assumes she's alive, then has to write back to someone he doesn't know explaining to *save your skin*, shame on you.

Answer (score 19):

I am in, more or less, your exact situation. My PhD supervisor died of a brain tumor in 2011. However, he did not leave behind a letter for me, nor am I on the market. I think you should be careful of the culture that you are applying in. If the culture demands, usually, that the letter be blind to the applicant, then you should probably not use it unless you state in your cover letter the reason why you have included it. If it's an open system, then you will probably benefit from it unless it's been 5 or 10 years since your recommender's passing. Either way, as the comments say, you should disclose what's going on.

Comment: it is open style letter. starting to whom it may concern. It is not old then 2 years.

Comment: @SSimon even it it's not an "open" letter, someone else may be able to send the letter on the deceased's behalf.  (I think I've seen a letter before that included a long except from a deceased advisor's previous letter.)

Answer (score 14):

One option would be to have the letter sent to a colleague who knows your work and was close to your late professor.  That person could then write you a letter which could incorporate some of the information from your late professor's letter.  For example, they could include an excerpt from that letter put into context.  This both gets around some of the ethical issues (since the new letter writer can explain that the old letter writer passed away) and also avoids some of the issues with the letter being out of date (since the new letter writer will be able to include comments on recent developments).

Comment: I know people that were close to her, but they were not related to my work at all. is that ok?

Comment: @SSimon: No, if I were them I would decline, because then they are recommending you without actually having any "authority" on which to do so. Awkward for both of you, potentially.

Answer (score 2):

I have no ethical qualms about using a letter from a deceased professor.  I would however also seek out at least one letter from a colleague of the professor, not because it's unethical but because only having a letter from a deceased professor will at least raise eyebrows.

Answer (score 1):

I have letters of recommendation, which I have publicly published (online).

I don't bother to keep track of whether each of the authors behind these letters continues to breathe.

If I found out that somebody has passed away, do you think I ought to go into my collection of published material and delete the content?  The person's life has been snubbed away from the planet.  You think I should go remove a positive thing that provides some ongoing evidence of this person's activity?

The point of these rhetorical questions is point out some of the reasoning to my opinion, which is obviously that it's fine to use the letter.  If I were on my death bed with a week to live, but I knew I could help someone by writing a letter of recommendation, and if I bothered to write that letter, I wouldn't want them to tear up the letter into pieces in a couple of weeks just because I will have left my death bed by that point.

Comment: will they check the letter? How realistically is that to happen?

Comment: @SSimon : Less likely than 30-50 years ago.  But still likely enough that I expect a high chance that some people check.